# Как выбрать нужное значение сформированное циклом for и помещённое в List отвечающее критериям условия

Tags: c#

Как взять нужное значение из List помещённое через цикл for отвечающее нужному условию. Я перебираю 10 элементов в контейнере с web страницы с помощью Selenium WebDriver через цикл for. Мне необходимо чтоб программа отреагировала когда в List появиться какое либо значение при котором сработает дальнейший блок кода. Например: это 10 значений по порядку:
for (int i=0; i<Procent.Count; i++)
Вывод полученного в List
0 - 8.00%
1 - 16.00%
2 - 12.00%
**3 - 0.00%**
4 - 24.00%
5 - 8.00%
6 - 16.00%
7 - 12.00%
8 - 32.00%
9 - 24.00%

Нужно при значении "0.00%" у любого от 0 до 9 присвоить переменной "peremennaya" то значение которое было по счёту верным 0.00%, например равным = 3 потому что у третьей по счёту получилось  = "0.00%" и так далее ели у 5-ой по счёту будет 0.00% то присвоить peremennaya  значение =5 и.т.д.
И если от 0 до 9 не у одного не найдено 0.00% то повторить ещё раз до тех пор пока не будет найдено значение 0.00% у любого из 0 до 9 по счёту в списке List.

Comment: `int peremennaya = myList.IndexOf("0.00%"); if (peremennaya >= 0) { ... }`. Если значение не найдено, переменная будет содержать `-1`.

Comment: Этот метод не работает и вызывает ошибку: не удается преобразовать из "string" в "OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement".

Comment: У меня плохое воображение, плохо представил ваш код.

Comment: перебирай у веб-елемента параметр то ли innerHtml то ли OuterHtml то ли Text

Comment: Я вот этой строчкой кода: 'List<IWebElement> Procent = Browser.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".highcharts-data-labels g tspan:nth-child(2)")).ToList();' собираю на Web странице в контейнере 10 элементов и загоняю это всё в List, через: 'for (int i=0; i<Procent.Count; i++)' чтобы найти значение "0.00%" через 'int prognoz_last_digit = Procent.IndexOf("0.00%");' и взять цифру индекса в котором 0.00%, Метод IndexOf выдал ошибку.  'int prognoz_last_digit = Procent.IndexOf(**"0.00%"**);'  это ошибка (не удаётся преобразовать из "string" в "OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement".).